# Ios Submission Issue with ipv6 on GCP

Tags: ios, google-cloud-platform, submission

Our server are build on GCP , but GCP networks do not support IPv6 at all.

How could I solve the problem to pass the IOS Submission.

Don't tell me I have to change service to AWS or Azune.

Any good idea will be appreciated. thanks a lot .

Comment: Did you get error from itunesconnect?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no requirement for your servers to be running on IPv6 environment. What error are you getting from the Apple review team? If apple team has mentioned about IPv6 in their rejection message it means that during the review process app was not able to connect to the servers. Please check that and you don't need to change your hosting environment.

Answer (score 0):

It's a new Apple policy pushing forward ipv6 connectivity. The only work around is implement Google Load Balancing: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/ipv6
The minimum will be $18 usd/month